# Swift and REST API authentication

Tags: java, swift, rest

I've built a REST API, which does token-header based authentication.

So if a user logs in, the response the client (the Swift device) will get is something in the json body `{}` and then a header which an authentication token.

Everytime I want to get data `GET` request from the API, I have to pass in this header before making the request.

Is the best (**secure**) way to accomplish this to create a constants file with the equivalent of `public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = (token received and set)` in Swift?

And then to make a request after login, get this constant from this file and proceed? Surely there has to be a better and more secure way?

Comment: Bump, any ideas?

Comment: File, CoreData, or UserDefault ... any place you think appropriate would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The most secure way to store the token is using the `Keychain`. This will also persist the token if they are to uninstall/reinstall the application. Where as `UserDefaults` and `CoreData` will remove the data on uninstall.